# How to check what user inputted items are in a list and calculate/derive a cost from it?

Tags: python

So I'm creating this program that involves the code asking the user for items he would like to purchase, and those items are then added into a list. My question is this, since the items are added into a list and each item holds a monetary value, how would I check if a specific/group of items are in the appended list and thus calculate a total cost?

e.g. user inputs `Chicken` and `Pork` and those items get added into `userOrder` list.

How would I check if the `userOrder` list contains those multiple items and not other items, and how would I then with the following items in the list be able to calculate a total cost?

I tried using the `if x in list`, but I don't know how to implement it in such a way that checks multiple items, would I use `and` or `or`?

```
def userChoose(decide):
    if decide == "Yes":
        pizzaPurch=input("Please enter the Pizza(s) you would like to
        purchase")
        userOrder.append(pizzaPurch)
        print("You purchased the following:")
        print(userOrder)

    if decide == "No":
       pizzaPurch=input("Please enter the pizza(s) you would like to
       purchase")
       userOrder.append(pizzaPurch)
       print("You purchased the following:")
       print(userOrder)
       return pizzaPurch, userOrder


banner()
decide = pizzaReg()
pizzaPrem(decide)
userChoose(decide)

if 'Pepperoni' in userOrder:
    print("You included Pepperoni Pizza in your purchase list")
```

I would like to have it so that once user inputs items he would like to purchase and thus gets added into a list, the code checks the items that are included, and what's not, and from there calculate a total cost. The code is incomplete as I'm at a loss and thus I can't provide actual results.

Comment: You're asking quite a few questions. You should probably break them up.

Comment: One problem I see is that `if decide == "Yes"` the `userChoose()` function will  return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what exactly you want, but if you want just to compare two lists, then you can do it like this:

```
userOrder = ['chicken', 'carrot', 'pork', 'onion']
pattern = ['pork','chicken']

matched = [item for item in pattern if item in userOrder]
matched

Output:
['pork', 'chicken']
```